# How to handle page refreshing

Tags: .htaccess, angularjs

With Angular's `html5Mode(true);` I can get my index page to end up with a `/setup` url.  This is great, except if the visitor hits F5 it'll break because `/setup` directory doesn't exist, it's only a simulated URL.

How can I be sure that the Angular mappings are correctly routed through `index.html` and read by Angular rather than the server trying to load an index file for `/setup`

Comment: Just leaving, so no time for a proper answer :) You need to setup your server to handle the routes, via .htaccess. See here -> http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anubhava's answer to me - is close.  You will most likely have more than just /setup in your app... You'll probably have several URLs, and with Anubhava's answer you'll have to edit your `.htaccess` file for each one.  Here is what I use, it forwards all requests to the index file, unless the file/directory being requested actually exists:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !OPTIONS
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must be able to achieve that with mod_rewrite. See how drupal makes use of it: http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls

I have not used Angular but rewrite can change url to anything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable direct access to /setup URL. Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+setup\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.hml [R=301,L]
```